# Ensure property in document is unique only if they have the same value of another property

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nonce

Let's say I have a schema like so:

```
const MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
    },
    nonce:{
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    }
});
```

How can I make sure that nonce is unique if the userId is the same? But documents with different userIds can have the same nonces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create unique compound index like :

```
   db.collection.createIndex({userId:1 , nonce:1 },unique: true)
```